# How to access first 5*5 block from an image in open cv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Can anyone please help me to access first 5*5 block from an image?I am new to open CV,I am doing the coding in  c++.i searched over net.If anyone could answer this it would make my work easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access image ROI using the `cv::Mat::operator()`.

e.g, to get the first 5x5 block of the image, you can do the following:

```
int roi_origin_x = 0;
int roi_origin_y = 0;
int block_width = 5;
int block_height = 5;

cv::Rect roi(roi_origin_x, roi_origin_y, block_width, block_height);

cv::Mat region = image(roi);
```

To access a specific block number e.g (i,j), just change the origin of the block like this:

```
int block_width = 5;
int block_height = 5;
int roi_origin_x =  i * block_width;
int roi_origin_y = j * block_height;

cv::Rect roi(roi_origin_x, roi_origin_y, block_width, block_height);
```

The roi may go out of image bounds, so make sure you apply the checks to keep it inside the image boundary,

Comment: @kadu.. Well, just keep on changing the origin. Check the update in answer.